# Congruences and division

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to show that $(x^p-x)/(x^2-1) \equiv 0 \mod p$. Is this correct:

$(x^{p-1}-1)x/(x^2-1) \equiv 0 \mod p$ by Fermat's little theorem.

My main concern is whether it is still the case when we are working with a fraction. Can we just consider the numerator and denominator separately?

Comment: No, if the (numerator)/(denominator) and both are divisible by $p$, then it is not true. For example, $(x^p-1)/(x-1) \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is $x \equiv1 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

We have to consider them both.

If both the numerator and the denominator are divisible by $p$, then it is not true that $$\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

It is similar to how $\frac{0}{0}$ is not defined.

For example, $\frac{(x^p-1)}{(x-1)} \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Note that this implies that your claim itself was wrong - take $x=4, p=3$.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to say p > 3!

Comment: @Mark Regardless, your claim is false. Take $x=6, p=5$. The result is $222$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html), $$\dfrac{x^p-x}{x^2-1}\equiv0\pmod{\dfrac p{(p,x^2-1)}}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{x^p-x}{x^2-1}\equiv0\pmod p$$

if $(p,x^2-1)=1$

Now as $p$ is prime, $p\nmid(x^2-1)\iff(p,x^2-1)=1$

and $p\mid(x^2-1)\iff x\equiv\pm1\pmod p$